# MVVM with EF Core - New entity as command parameter with bound properties in viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mvvm, entity-framework-core

After looking more into the MVVM Pattern in Xamarin.Forms I wrapped all my ViewModel functions into commands and call them from the XAML in my pages. In addition, I want to assure testability through my commands, so I pass dependencies as a command parameter.

I have a page where a new entity can be created and added to the ef core database.

After the user filled in all needed values into the components and therefore the ViewModel properties are set, and the page's button is clicked, the entity should be added to the database.

My code representing the described behaviour:

AppointmentViewModel.cs:

```
public class AppointmentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Bound properties
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    // Command to add new appointment
    public ICommand AddAppointmentCommand { get; }

    // The appointment entity which will be passed as a command parameter
    public Appointment BoundAppointment => new Appointment(Title, Date);

    AppointmentViewModel()
    {
        AddAppointmentCommand = new Command<Appointment>(async a => await AddAppointment(a));
    }

    public async Task AddAppointment(Appointment appointment)
    {
        // Code to add an appointment to the database through Entity Framework core
    }
}
```

AppointmentPage.xaml:

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddAppointmentCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding BoundAppointment}"/>
```

The problem I'm currently facing is that the Property `BoundAppointment` is only initialized when the page is opened, and therefore no values were supplied by the user.

So when the command is executed, the created entity hasn't the values the user-supplied. (The Title and Date still have their default values)

I want to pass my entity as a command parameter but with all the supplied values.
Sadly I didn't found a solution to this, which can assure testability of my commands eg. in unit tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So when the command is executed, the created entity hasn't the values the user-supplied. (The Title and Date still have their default values)

From your code, you have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged, but you don't implement all the setter rules of each property of viewmodel.
You can try to modify your code according to the following code.

```
public class AppointmentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Bound properties
    private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            _Title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }
    private DateTime _Date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set
        {
            _Date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Date");
        }
    }

    // Command to add new appointment
    public ICommand AddAppointmentCommand { get; }

    // The appointment entity which will be passed as a command parameter
    private Appointment _BoundAppointment;
    public Appointment BoundAppointment
    {
        get { return _BoundAppointment; }
        set
        {
            _BoundAppointment = new Appointment(Title, Date);
            RaisePropertyChanged("BoundAppointment");
        }
    }

    AppointmentViewModel()
    {
        AddAppointmentCommand = new Command<Appointment>(async a => await AddAppointment(a));
    }

    public async Task AddAppointment(Appointment appointment)
    {
        // Code to add an appointment to the database through Entity Framework core
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

When Title and Date value changed, you can update `BoundAppointment`

```
private string _Title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return _Title; }
        set
        {
            _Title = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Title");
            BoundAppointment = new Appointment(Title, Date);
        }
    }
    private DateTime _Date;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return _Date; }
        set
        {
            _Date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Date");
            BoundAppointment = new Appointment(Title, Date);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)
I implemented OnPropertyChanged() for ```Title``` and ```Date``` but missed this in the example code in my question. 

Now I implemented the Setter for ```BoundAppointment``` as well and tested it again. 
The question I have is how the Setter is invoked so the object is correctly initialized with new bounded values of ```Title``` and ```Date```. This isn't accomplished by the command binding in xaml only.

Comment: @N.iw  **The question I have is how the Setter is invoked so the object is correctly initialized with new bounded values of Title and Date**, you mean that you want to update  `BoundAppointment` when Title and Date changed? If yes, you can update `BoundAppointment` in Title and Date's setter. Please see my update.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's working just perfectly. Wonder how I didn't think of this myself :)